# I cannot create core in Solr 5.2.1

Tags: solr

I have solr clouds 5.2.1. I deploy solr and zookeeper. When I try to create a core this errors are throwing :

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core contracts_shard1_replica1: Error loading solr config from solrconfig.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:78)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:635)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:611)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:628)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:213)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:193)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:431)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)


org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'contracts_shard1_replica1': Unable to create core [contracts_shard1_replica1] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/contracts', cwd=C:\CM_10.1.0\INDEXSERVER\searchserver-distribution\target\searchserver\solr\server
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:661)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:213)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:193)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:431)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
]
```

I created **contracts** inside of **C:\CM_10.1.0\INDEXSERVER\searchserver-distribution\target\searchserver\solr\server** and copied " conf" folder which is in solr\configsets\basic_configs" into **contracts**. But problem didn't solved.
I do need help to solve this problem. Does anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Could you put your log output into a code block? It would be much easier to read. Just use the `{}` icon in the edit toolbar.

Comment: I added code block to the log. I have been struggling this error more than three days. If anyone help me to solve it i'll be very happy

Comment: That `SolrException` states that it can't find the `solrconfig.xml` file. Do you have one? If so, where is it?

Comment: Yes I have solrconfig.xml  in this folders:

Comment: Yes I have solrconfig.xml  in this folders:
\INDEXSERVER\searchserver-distribution\target\searchserver\solr\server\solr\configsets\sample_techproducts_configs\conf
INDEXSERVER\searchserver-distribution\target\searchserver\solr\server\solr\configsets\data_driven_schema_configs\conf
INDEXSERVER\searchserver-distribution\target\searchserver\solr\server\solr\configsets\basic_configs\conf

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the zookeeper, you must first send the config files to the zookeeper. I'm not sure how it is in Windows :P, but in Linux it would be:

```
cd /searchserver/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts

./zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -confdir /searchserver/solr/server/solr/corename/conf -confname myconfname -z zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
```

In Windows, use zkcli.bat in the same directory.
Another way to do this is by adding

```
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/corename/conf/"
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dcollection.configName=myconfname"
```

to the solr.in.sh file, then (re)starting solr. In Windows, the file is solr.in.cmd, and you add the following lines:

```
set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/corename/conf/
set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dcollection.configName=myconfname
```

The solr.in.sh/solr.in.cmd file is included into the solr (colr.cmd) command that you use to start the solr server. Myconfname above (in both methods) is an arbitrary name you give to indicate the sets of config files that you've added to the zookeeper. Then you can create the core using the collections API:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=coreName&numShards=2&shards=shard1,shard2&collection.configName=myconfname&createNodeSet=localhost:8983_solr
```

Comment: We have deploy.bat we use it to create solr and zookeeper instace, start and stop solr.
When we run deploy.bat 1 it creates one solr and one zookeeper instance.
when we run deploy.bat stop it stops solr and zookeeper
Should I add the  SOLR_OPTS to this bat file ?
One another things is there is zkcli.bat files in the folder you gave.
I have question about the first command

about corename --> I want to create contracts core, so I think corename should be contracts
confname --> is this solrconfig.xml ?

Comment: In Windows the environment variables (SOLR_OPTS) are set in the file solr.in.cmd, which is called on by solr.cmd in the same (solr/bin) directory. I would guess your deploy.bat runs solr.cmd, so try changing solr.in.cmd. The windows equivalent of zkcli.sh is zkcli.bat, and is used int he same way. The "confname" is something you make up to refer to the whole set of config files that you have uploaded to the zookeeper for that core. You can see the configs that you have added listed in the admin console under Cloud -> Tree -> /configs.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the above comment that I made.